# Resetting all checkboxes which are present over few pages

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, checkbox

I have a pop up window which loads up with almost 127 checkboxes having the name('parties'), with a view of 10 checkboxes per page(13 pages).

I have a reset button, on clicking which, 'doReset()' function is called. I want to reset(checked=false) all the checkboxes, when reset button is clicked.

I tried doing,

```
function doReset(){ 
  document.forms[0].reset();
  }
```

But this is clearing the selected checkboxes of only page 1, while the checkboxes which were selected in other pages are not getting cleared. I am a novice at jsp and javascript. Advise me with this !!!

**P.S:**
Even tried

```
function doReset(){ 
  document.forms[0].reset();
  var w = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
      for(var i = 0; i < w.length; i++){ 
      if(w[i].type=='checkbox'){ 
      w[i].checked = false; 
  }
  }
  }
```

Still clearing checkboxes of page 1 only and not the others.

Comment: Are yo pre-fetching all the 13 pages or the pages load (in browser) as and when you request them ?

Comment: Looks like your pagination is made by ajax or on some data that you aren't handling, that's why you can't update all the checks at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function doReset(){

        var checkBxs = document.getElementsByName('partiesChBx');
        document.forms[0].selectdRwIds.value="";
        for(var i = 0; i < checkBxs.length; i++){
        checkBxs[i].checked = false; 
        }
}
```

Actually this code did the trick. The problem was because of the `selectdRwIds`, which was saving having a value even after it was made "".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work but no harm in trying:

$('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');

or the following

$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() 
{ 
        this.checked = false; 
});